# Unable to resolve service for type [DBcontext] while attempting to activate page model

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I am currently programming an Asp.Net Project for my A-Level Computing.

I'm trying to access my Database Context (UserGameKeyContext) so that I can update it by adding a new record. However, when I initialise the page /Play (where I am attempting to add this new record among other things) I get this error;

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 
'Project_With_Identity.Models.UserGameKeyContext' while attempting to activate 
'Project_With_Identity.Pages.PlayModel'.
```

My current issue is that and all other answers that I've seen related to this error are more related to interfaces than Databases specifically.

Here is /Play

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor;
using Project_With_Identity.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Project_With_Identity.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Project_With_Identity.Models;

namespace Project_With_Identity.Pages
{
    public class PlayModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<Project_With_IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<Project_With_IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserGameKeyContext _gamekeycontext;
        public PlayModel(
            UserManager<Project_With_IdentityUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<Project_With_IdentityUser> signInManager,
            UserGameKeyContext gameKeyContext)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _gamekeycontext = gameKeyContext; 
        }

        //edited for Brevity
    }
}
```

UserGameKeyContext gameKeyContext appears to be the problem - whenever I try and load the /Play page, I get the aforementioned error.

Here is UserGameKeyContext too;

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Project_With_Identity.Models;
using Project_With_Identity.Areas.Identity;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace Project_With_Identity.Models
{
    public class UserGameKeyContext : DbContext
    {
        public UserGameKeyContext() : base("UserGameKeyContext")
            {
            }

        public DbSet<UserGameKey> UserGameKeys { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Add();
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do, then, is to get /play to load UserGameKeyContext, so that later in my /play code I have a context variable that I can access and modify, mainly so that I can add new records to the database. If I'm intialising this database entirely wrong, I'd love to know so I can get back on the right track - otherwise, help understanding and fixing this problem will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register all injected types with .NET dependency injection regardless of whether they are interfaces or concrete classes.

In *Startup.cs*, you can do the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    // Other stuff...
    services.AddDbContext<UserGameKeyContext>();
}
```

**Further reading:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

Comment: I added Services.AddDbContext<>, basically exactly the same as the standard template Services.AddDbContext<>, but now I'm getting an exception;

```
Cannot Convert lambda expression to type 'ServiceLifetime' Because it is not a delegate type
```
Error. I'm not sure what's wrong, and trying to find answers on google yields no helpful fixes

Comment: @IsabelleSHACKLETON Can you update your question with the code from ConfigureServices?

Comment: No need, I've managed to fix the issue - My Context class was using System.Data.Entity and was built as such rather than being built like a EntityFrameworkCore context. I modified the context so that it was built like it would be in EntityFrameworkCore, and I managed to get the migrations of the database to work because of it. Thanks for your help

Comment: @IsabelleSHACKLETON Glad to hear you got it working. The transition from .NET to .NET Core is a little muddled due to the various slight changes and documentation not being explicit about those so I sympathize. If the answer I provided helped with the original dependency injection issue, please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks